# sql server trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

Hi I need a trigger in sql server 2005 that will update a table on another Sql server. Is that possible and what is the syntax?

Thanks

--MB

Comment: What a dreadful idea.  What's wrong with an application program that updates two databases?

Comment: Are you trying to copy an entire row of a table or just one field? You could make use of mirroring but that's probably overkill for this situation.

Comment: every record entered into this table should be copied into similar table in another database on another sql server

Comment: i agree with s.lott, but this is what it has to be for now.

Comment: Then take a look at mirroring in sql server, it may well provide what you need: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917680.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @S.Lott that this is a horrific idea. I would suggest creating a job to affect the change to the secondary server (push). You can reduce the data latency simply by increasing the frequency of you job. Of course this means that the `SELECT` and subsequent `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` on the secondary server must be quick. If you are anxious about the `SELECT`, you could design a trigger to insert records into a local queue table and simply select from that queue table in your job to affect your desired change on the secondary server.